# How to classify and localize noisy circles with convolutional neural networks[tensorflow]

Tags: localization, tensorflow, geometry, conv-neural-network

I've got the task to find and locate circles(markers) in medical pictures(x-ray) by an neural network. 
The pictures A [800x600, grayimage] are very noisy and contain structures like bones and circles/markers.

First of all I build a dataset of pictures for training the classifier.
I save from the 800x600 pictures the areas which contain circles with the size 28x28 (label=Marker). The circles itself got different intensity levels ([click here to see an example circle picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Xki.png)) Sometimes the circles are partly overlaid by bones. Furthermore I save some areas which not contain circles(label=NoMarker).
Each of this training image has the size 28x28.
(Database 100'000 pictures size 28x28, half of it with circle, the other half without). I save all of this [28x28] images and labels to the same format as the minst dataset(idx3/idx1).

I started to build an classifier based on the tensorflow mnist_softmax example and got an accuracy of round about 90 percent.

The code look like this:

```
# Read my  Datasets, code adapted from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist:
# train_image [28x28] pixel, and the labels
mnist = read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Train
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
for i in range(2000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(2000)
  train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

# Test trained model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy"+ str(accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})))
```

After this I try to localise the pixels in the circle.
For localization I take a sliding window approach. That means that I run other a 800x600 picture take always the area in the sliding window(28x28) as an input for my trained neural networked. The result of the NN is the propabily that this window contains a circle. This results are saved in a matrix/picture:

*Result of localisation*:

[image: Result of localisation in the complete picture, Red and gray pixels mean circle detected for this pixel]
[Edited]: I have marked the circles red which was correctly classified in the Picture. The intensity of the  graylevel stands for the probability to be an circle[black pixel =100% inside a circle, white pixel=0% inside a pixel]. So in best case there should only be red points and the rest of the picture should be white.

It seems to me that the geometrie/curves of the circle is not involved in the learning process.
Im very new in the field machine learning. Is there a got possibility/ model I could use for this task.
Best regards,
Kater

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? If your question basically "is there a better approach?" then please make it clear what is insufficient in your current solution.

Comment: The problem in the current approach is that for example also the border of the bones are detected as circles(even if the shape of the bones are straight lines). May be you know a better neural network then mnist which could learn more about the geometry of a circle? Could using a network with for example using more layers(convolutional, maxpooling) help to solve this problem?

Comment: I was just commenting on the question in general, because it seems interesting but in the current form it might not be a good fit for the Q&A form of StackOverflow. Maybe you could edit the post to include some of your code and perhaps indicate on the image the false positive areas.

Comment: Yes, and could you also describe **in details** the dataset you have? You say you have 800*600 images, but the training data consists of patches of 28*28 of these images, with a label indicating whether the patch contains a circle?

Comment: When you write `y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])` I suppose you don't have 10 labels but only 2?

Comment: Yes you are right, I only have 2 labels. But I used the structure of mnist there are 10 classes/labels. Not good for the performance, but it works for the moment ;)

Comment: Last question: how much 600*800 labeled images do you have in total?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. @Olivier more than 10000 of these pictures.